# haw to create slideshow 3d

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have a view and i want when i change the orientation this view a slideshow appear

how is called this function and how to do this kind of thing...?
[image]

Comment: You have to be a bit more thorough, and please ask a question, change the title of the question then.

Comment: 3D slideshow, for all those who don't speak French. The rest of the question... beats me!

Comment: I want to make when I change my view changes direction with a movie or slideshow of pictures I have already registered in a table

Comment: Looks like he submitted the question before he finished typing it...

Comment: Ahhhh, you mean you want a 3D carousel! Give us your code, you say it's already in a table - give us the format and give us something to work with. We can help but you have to give us as much information as possible. Not just "how can I do this: [picture]"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look Here:

[Quartz Composer 3D Carousel (and loading images within an iterator)](http://memo.tv/quartz_composer_3d_carousel_and_loading_images_within_an_iterator)

This is a tutorial about how to make something very similar to your example. You may have to either adjust the tutorial code or your own code to make them fit together.

Edit: Just realised the link to the tutorial in that article is broken.

You may have more success creating something like [this](http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.m) and adapting it.